# Where do you place the homepage on a sitemap?

Tags: information-architecture, sitemap

Simple question really: on your site maps, do you always place the homepage (if existant) as the top single level of a site map, or do you treat it as a sibling on the other main level pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, or you can say www.yoursite.com and have it a page under that. I have seen it both ways.

However, it makes the most sense to start with it since most if not all your users will.